# ERROR: Line: 4: Library: FindAverageValue: TypeError: list is undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var list = [42, 23, 32, 11];
var average = FindAverageValue.findAverage(list);
console.log("Average value: " + average);
```

Above code is a separate code to try out my library, and below is the code of my library

```
//Function exported in the library (code in line 2 above)
function findAverage(list) {
//Makes sure that function doesn't do anything if there is nothing in the list (checks if list is empty)
if (list.length === 0) {
    return 0;
 }
var sum = 0;
//Loops to add the numbers in the list
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + list[i];
 }
//Finds the average by dividing the sum and the length of the list
var average = sum / list.length;
console.log(average);
return average;
}
findAverage();
```

Comment: The problem is you call `findAverage();` right after it with no parameters. The `list` parameter will therefore be undefined. You should not be using `var`; by now, new Javascript code should use `let` and there is no reason to use an old-fashioned C-style `for` loop to loop over the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Library code
function findAverage(list) {
   // Makes sure that function doesn't do anything if there is nothing in the list (checks if list is empty)
   if (list.length === 0) {
       return 0;
   }
   var sum = 0;
   // Loops to add the numbers in the list
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       sum = sum + list[i];
   }
   // Finds the average by dividing the sum and the length of the list
   var average = sum / list.length;
   console.log(average);
   return average;
}

// Separate code using the library
var list = [42, 23, 32, 11];
var average = findAverage(list); // Corrected function call
console.log("Average value: " + average);
```